# error executing child request for handler 'system.Web.HttpHandlerUtil+serverExecuteHttphandlerAsynWrapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

mylogin page is a partialview .
and i use    **@html.Action("LogOn")**

but it can't in my  Logon action ,redirect to "mainIndex" .
and says :

```
       error executing child request for handler 'system.Web.HttpHandlerUtil+serverExecuteHttphandlerAsynWrapper
```

i changed **@html.Action("LogOn")** to    **@{html.RenderAction ("LogOn")}** , but didn't diffrent .
 and changed to    **@{Html.partialView("LogOn")}** but the error :

```
    The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.Models.UsersClass+LogOn'.
```

MY CODE:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LogOn(String returnUrl)
         {

        using (var db = new pakalaContext())
        {
            UsersClass.LogOn AllFeatureToLog = new UsersClass.LogOn();

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) //remember me
            {
                MyClass obj = new MyClass();
                if (obj.shouldRedirect(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
            }

            return PartialView(AllFeatureToLog);
        }
    }



    public MyProject.Models.AccountModels.ControlUsers MembershipService { get; set; }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(UsersClass.LogOn loginInfo, string returnUrl)
    {


        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(loginInfo.usernam, loginInfo.password))
                {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInfo.usernam,   loginInfo.RememberMe);
                MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
                if (obj1.shouldRedirect(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("MainIndex", "Home");
                }
                                }

            else
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError("LoginError", "incorrec pass or username");

            }
        }



        return PartialView(loginInfo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the `LogOn()` action requires 2 parameters. You cannot call simply `@{ RenderAction("LogOn"); }`, you shall add the parameters, like:

```
@{ 
    var loginInfo = new UsersClass.LogOn() { /* Stuff */ };
    var url = Request.Url.ToString();
    Html.RenderAction("LogOn", new { loginInfo = loginInfo, returnUrl = url });
}
```

So the problem was that the framework was searching for a `LogOn()` action with no parameters, but there was none. Because it was called as a child action, you get this non quite verbose error.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has came here (like me) looking for a solution to the above error in nopCommerce 3.10 when publishing modified source code to a deployment server, the issue for me was caused by missing plugins (I found this out by checking the Log table in the DB).

This is due to the fact that there are actually 2 build scripts for preparing and deploying the code (prepare.bat and deploy.bat) that you must run to build the source code when publishing source code - these build the Nop.Web and Nop.Administration web apps separately and copy the relevant files/plugins to the relevant places. It creates a deployable diretory that you can copy to your deployment server.

Hope this helps someone.